# How to separate a vector into two vectors, one having the first half of my original vector and the other having the second half

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of `n` vectors with an even length. Let us make an easy example with 3 vectors of length=4:

```
 a={a1,a2,a3,a4}
 b={b1,b2,b3,b4}
 c={c1,c2,c3,c4}
```

I want to create the vectors:

```
 d1={a1,a2}
 d2={a3,a4}

 e1={b1,b2}
 e2={b3,b4}

 f1={c1,c2}
 f2={c3,c4}
```

I suppose I have to use `GatherBy`, but I have not found the way to get what I want.

Comment: Have a look at `Partition`.

Comment: This is the latest of many questions you have asked that are all incorrectly tagged [sparse-arrays]. Please ensure that you use tags that are relevant to the topic of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4}; b = {b1, b2, b3, b4}; c = {c1, c2, c3, c4}; 
{d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2} = Partition[Join[a, b, c], 2]
```

Also

```
{{d1, d2}, {e1, e2}, {f1, f2}} = Partition[#, 2] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds! +1, I respectfully withdrawal

Comment: Actually wouldn't this prove more general for even lengthed lists: {{d1, d2}, {e1, e2}, {f1, f2}} = 
  Partition[#, Length[#]/2] & /@ {a, b, c};

Comment: @Jagra The question could be "generalized" in every direction you may think of :) . I really dislike naming sublists like that, no need.